# Cannot access CollapsingToolbar View

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a Navigation Drawer Activity `(NavActivity.java)`, which has a fragment `(HomeFrag)` with a recyclerView. When a user selects an item from the recyclerView, it replaces the current fragment with this one (`itemFrag`):

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
                                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                             android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                             android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="192dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary">


        <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
            android:id="@+id/nivSplash"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

            <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                android:id="@+id/nivIcon"
                android:layout_width="96dp"
                android:layout_height="96dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:background="@mipmap/splash_land"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/nivIcon"
                android:background="#AA000000"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/tvName"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/nivIcon"
                android:background="#AA000000"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvRole"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/nivIcon"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/nivIcon"
                android:background="#AA000000"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
                android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryTransparent"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:textColor="#fff"/>

        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Now, I cannot access the collapseBar's views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't see your code, but try this:

In fragment:

```
CollapsingToolbarLayout collapseLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout)getActivity.findViewById(R.id.yourcollapsingtoolbar);
```

And try to change them

Comment: That worked! :D Do you know how to fix the other 2 problems?

Comment: ViewPager not appears or not appear it's content?

Comment: ViewPager doesn't appear at all, but I am not getting any errors. I'll upload the Java code in a sec